# Deleting Microsoft graph fails with ExtensionError

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, subscription

I am trying to delete a webhook subscription to Microsoft graph.
My http call is:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/3ecdf72f-f302-49f6-851c-d04d178a9ref
```

I got the id of the subscription using:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

As response I am getting this error:

```
{
   "error": {         
     "code": "ExtensionError",         
     "message": "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",         
    "innerError": {"request-id": "2c61eba9-86c8-4420-9276-d6581fd3c5b7",             "date": "2018-10-30T15:11:57"}     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are investigating a bug where sometimes subscriptions will be orphaned in the system. The actual subscription was originally removed and notifications are not being sent.
You should expect the subscription to be removed properly from the system in the next few days, as we fix the bug. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Hey Peter,  we are experiencing this currently, what should we be looking at, I suspect this is resolved by now ? Many thanks in advance.