# Microsoft Graph DELETE subscription request fails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I accidentally let my subscriptions expire last night. When I sat down at work this morning, graph notifications were not flowing into my application and `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/` returned no subscriptions. I created new subscriptions successfully, but am still not receiving notifications from Graph.

So, I am trying to cleanup the subscriptions I created this morning to troubleshoot. In doing so I reached a subscription that results in an error when deleting.

I first request `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/` to retrieve a list of active subscriptions. From that response, I get the id `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

I then send a request to `DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

This returns the following response

```
404 NOT FOUND

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "date": "2018-12-13T20:36:36"
        }
    }
}
```

In my research into this error, I came across this SO question: [Deleting Microsoft graph fails with ExtensionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067562/deleting-microsoft-graph-fails-with-extensionerror)

The answer suggests that my subscription has been orphaned. Could this have been the original problem with the original expired subscriptions?

Any advice or experience in this matter?

Comment: some more information: my webhook endpoint just received a `created` notification for a message in my inbox. The notification has a `subscriptionId` that does not get returned in `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/`. Is it possible that the notifications are lagged by quite a bit of time? I haven't seen an actual new message in my inbox for at least 2 hours.

Comment: overnight, my webhook endpoint logged 38 incoming requests, each with subscriptionIds that existed yesterday during troubleshooting but were deleted before yesterday afternoon (with the exception of the one above). This leads me to believe that there is a massive lag in these subscriptions being processed.

Comment: friday 12/14, webhook requests started rollining as expected. I see other SO questions with a response from MSFT; about a problem that was resolved. I came in this morning to work, 12/17 and created to subscriptions. I am back to getting no webhook requests (i see and properly respond to the endpoint validation requests upon creating the subscription). `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/` returns valid subscriptions. is there a lock out or something when a subscription expires?

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks had an issue going on when notifications were delayed on 12/17 between 5:20am PST and 8am PST. If you are still having issues, can you please share the requestId and timestamp from the failed requests so we can investigate further. Thanks.