# Microsoft Graph Subscription ExtensionError - Delete / Update

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-webhooks

### Issue

- I currently have an Azure Active Directory Application that has a Microsoft Graph Webhook Subscription listening for new emails (messages) in a specified mailbox.
- The subscription has a scheduled task that renews the subscription's expiration date via an Update request. The subscription is targeted using its MS Graph Provided ID.
- **Any DELETE or UPDATE request against this specific subscription fails.** *(See 'Error Response' below.)*

---

### Question

- I realize that this may be the same issue / bug as the question presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111286/7902641
- Has there been any fix / resolution / or workaround for this?
- If there has been a fix or this is a different problem altogether, what can I do to resolve this specific issue?
- Thanks!

---

### Error Response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The subscription with Id 'Q0IzOUZCMTYtMTk4OC00OEZDLUFFQjQtNzI4NTU1MDREMkVDXzQ5RDk2MzI3LUFDRDEtNEE2QS05QTQ1LUYwQ0ZGQjgwNEQ0Qg==' is not found.]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e83fe463-....-....-....-76eb35e2e697",
      "date": "2019-03-22T02:35:14"
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Extra Info

- Somehow the Microsoft Graph ID for the subscription is...transformed? The original subscription ID is *( 528b79f1-....-....-....-360c0e1149e9 )* and the returned target ID is: *( Q0IzOUZ ... NEQ0Qg== )* .
- The executing UPDATE request originates from an ASP.NET CORE application, using the Microsoft Graph SDK (C#).

  - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet
- However I have eliminated the SDK as the origination of the problem -- using a REST API tester (Insomnia), I achieve the same error result. The request URL looks like:

  - *https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/528b79f1-....-....-....-360c0e1149e9*
- I have also attempted to use the BETA version instead of v1.0. Unfortunately I get the same error result.

---

### Configuration

- Application:

  - *Registered Azure Active Directory Daemon Application*
- Authentication Library:

  - *MSAL*
  - *https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet*
- Calling Application (generating the update / delete request):

  - *ASP.NET CORE (2.1) - Web Api*
  - *Using MS Graph SDK (Github link posted above)*

---

### *==  Update  ==*

- The subscription in question has now expired and disappeared from my application's subscriptions list *(timestamp, PST: 3/22/2019 8:45:22 AM)*.
- I will no longer be able to test against it (sorry S.O. posterity!).
- However, good news: now that the problem child (subscription) in question is gone, I was able to create a new subscription and restart my affected service. I am able to successfully submit get / update / delete requests against any newly created subscriptions.

---

Comment: We are observing the same behaviour from both Beta and v1.0. This seems like a regression, since it has been working fine for the last ~8 months. Is there a fix for this? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisVo This being a regression issue seems to be likely, but is (so far) unconfirmed. I am still not aware of a fix. However I have not yet encountered the issue as described in the post with my current Graph subscriptions.

Comment: Can I suggest you add your update as the answer? This way it'll make it easier for people to review the conclusion and it won't leave the question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### == Update ==
>
> - The subscription in question has now expired and disappeared from my application's subscriptions list (timestamp, PST: 3/22/2019 8:45:22
>     AM).
> - I will no longer be able to test against it (sorry S.O. posterity!).
> - However, good news: now that the problem child (subscription) in question is gone, I was able to create a new subscription and restart
>     my affected service. I am able to successfully submit get / update /
>     delete requests against any newly created subscriptions.

As this post is almost a year old and was most likely resolved via a fix by MSFT (no actionable fixes in our implementations), I am marking this post as "answered".

[@baywet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808675/baywet) Thank you for the suggestion to do so.

Comment: Just wanted to leave a note for posterity.  I've been managing some Teams subscriptions for a similar solution and all of the sudden I can't delete a subscription with the exact same behavior from O.P.  The delete request is being sent with the ID of the subscription, but the error message indicates that a different ID cannot be found.  The id is being transformed.  If I list subscriptions, I see the one I want to change.  When I attempt to GET or DELETE that subscription, I get this same "ExtensionError" as O.P.  Now I'm just waiting for my subscription to expire.....