# "Not Found" error in updating Microsoft Graph subscription for calendar mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I realize this question might be a duplicate of [Microsoft Graph Subscription ExtensionError - Delete / Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292161/microsoft-graph-subscription-extensionerror-delete-update), but since the original question doesn't have an answer yet and I decided to write another post here and put more details on it.

Currently, our application is synchronizing calendar mailboxes across several Microsoft tenant IDs. In the past several days (from March 21), some of our subscription update operations are starting to fail with `Not Found` error.

Several examples of such cases (there are also other cases but I wrote 2 examples here):

```
Microsoft tenant ID: 875bdd0a-688b-41d2-96b7-454d280043aa
Subscription ID: 7f8ed6ec-b536-4dad-b66a-5f6803f86121
Last known successful update: 2019-03-22 (10:17:06.008) UTC
When the update operation failed for the first time: 2019-03-23 (22:17:07.000) UTC

Other subscription ID which is okay for this tenant:
- c3b33905-61bf-42d0-94ed-fcfbe11ca71e
```

```
Microsoft tenant ID: 7eec492c-a8a4-4177-9059-77ec8ee8c987
Subscription ID: 4abc3eda-470a-459f-9bca-336c07706047
Last known successful update: 2019-03-22 (22:17:04.430) UTC
When the update operation failed for the first time: 2019-03-23 (22:17:12.000) UTC

Other subscription ID which is okay for this tenant:
- 27892e7d-0798-4324-8c0e-4ef87b27c047
```

Since we are trying to renew *almost-expired-subscription* every 12 hours, every consecutive calls to the problematic subscriptions will also return `Not Found` error.

Those subscriptions have basically expired by now, our only option is to create a new subscription.

**My question is**, do we know why this error occurred? Is this an intermittent issue or is there any chance it will happen again in the future?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm if your application uses user-delegated authentication or app-only authentication? This is relevant, because there are some Outlook behaviors that are based on that and they are not fully implemented in Graph, yet (will be soon)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. We are currently using user-delegated authentication. Since it works for some of the subscriptions and now it seems to work properly after I created a new subscription for those calendar mailboxes, my guess is there's an intermittent issue on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Subscriptions created against Outlook (Exchange) resources, such as messages, events, contacts, can be removed by the Outlook service due to user events such as password reset.
This causes a strange situation when you still see your Graph subscription, but the underlying Outlook subscription has been removed. This manifests itself in two ways:

1. You cannot renew or delete the Graph subscription, you see a 404 (generated by Outlook)
2. Notifications actually stop flowing to your app, for that subscription.

We are very close to updating Microsoft Graph to send you special signals informing you when this happens, so your app can take action and maintain continuous flow of notifications.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. By the way, what kind of user events might cause this error? After running our trial environment for 2 months with several O365 tenants, we still encountered this `ExtensionError, Operation: Update; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The subscription with Id '...' is not found.]` error quite often. Is there any update to the special signals feature? Thanks.

Comment: yes, please refer to this new preview feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-outlook-authz