# Why is Microsoft Graph list subscriptions returning what it is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to set up webhooks to update my apps database after a contact has been changed in Outlook. I want to manipulate the subscriptions I have set up in order to update them before they expire. At the moment I am doing a query to get the list of subscriptions I currently have, and the response I am getting is confusing.

I get an initial response, with a list of 154 subscriptions that have all expired (and my understanding is that they should not show up if they have expired.) as well as a nextLink.
example (current date 4/9/19)

```
applicationId: "afa7c255-37b2-4cb1-af0e-bf7bad39ed98"
changeType: "updated"
clientState: null
creatorId: "7e47df1e-7f11-45ca-a89a-d63dc83fdfa6"
expirationDateTime: "2019-04-04T18:17:05.192Z"
id: "cd80f682-45d2-496c-9e96-b39656803787"
notificationUrl: "https://us-central1-batteries-fb.cloudfunctions.net/graphContactSubscription"
resource: "users/cgomez@kbirecycling.com/contacts"
```

I then preform another request following the nextLink, and I receive a list of 532 subscriptions that all have an expiration date that is a week from the current day. This is concerning because according to Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0) any request that passes the maximum length allowed should fail, and therefore never have been created.
example (current date 4/9/19)

```
applicationId: "afa7c255-37b2-4cb1-af0e-bf7bad39ed98"
changeType: "updated"
clientState: null
creatorId: "7e47df1e-7f11-45ca-a89a-d63dc83fdfa6"
expirationDateTime: "2019-04-15T16:40:59.2650236Z"
id: "452c3780-3a87-4d75-a3db-079aa2e4d69c"
notificationUrl: "https://us-central1-batteries-fb.cloudfunctions.net/graphContactSubscription"
resource: "users/sfreeland@retrievtech.com/contacts"
```

Following the finding of these invalid subscriptions, I am attempting to delete them from my application, and I get an unusual response (which i believe has to do with [Deleting Microsoft graph fails with ExtensionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067562/deleting-microsoft-graph-fails-with-extensionerror/53111286#53111286))

```
 { code: 'ExtensionError',
     message:
      "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The subscription with Id 'QzAxODMzRTMtNzQ1Mi00OTIxLUExRjUtRTFDNjBGMTI1NTU0XzQ3RkYzQTg0LUY3OEUtNEI0Ni1BNjk3LUU4QTE4QjREREJERA==' is not found.]",
     innerError:
      { 'request-id': 'dcc27bf9-2c38-4770-b743-2629a1e038fc',
        date: '2019-04-09T17:49:21' } } }
```

This response looks very similar to the response in [Microsoft Graph Subscription ExtensionError - Delete / Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292161/microsoft-graph-subscription-extensionerror-delete-update) question, except he never found a solution except waiting past their expiration date, which allowed him to continue on. My list of subscriptions are well past their expiration and still in my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the latest update of the [question you pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292161/microsoft-graph-subscription-extensionerror-delete-update), this was a temporary issue which got addressed.